# Use DTD to Define an Element as CDATA?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, dtd, cdata

In short, is it possible to use a DTD to define an **element** as containing CDATA?

I'm calling a third party API that produces some invalid characters inside an element.  Specifically, the data contains some HTML entities like `&rsquo;`.  When I attempt to parse this XML using SimpleXML, I of course get a parser error "Entity 'rsquo' not defined".  Here's a simplistic example structure of what I'm dealing with:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <name>Jim Smith</name>
        <description>Jim&rsquo;s description breaks my parser</description>
    </item>
</items>
```

Since I don't have control to fix the API response... I've resorted to this dirty trick to inject a CDATA section inside the problem element just before I try to parse it:

```
$xml = str_replace("<description>", "<description><![CDATA[", $xml);
$xml = str_replace("</description>", "]]></description>", $xml);
```

This fixes the issue for me, but the overhead is probably too big, don't you think?  The XML can be anywhere between 30K to 100K of data.

I'd rather use a DTD but for the life of me I can't find any specs that allow for defining **CDATA** (in the same way I can define *PCDATA*).  Below is what I'd **like** to do, but of course, it's invalid because of the '#CDATA' definition I'm trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE ITEMS [
    <!ELEMENT ITEMS (ITEM)>
    <!ELEMENT ITEM (NAME, DESCRIPTION)>
    <!ELEMENT NAME (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT DESCRIPTION (#CDATA)>
]>
```

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in SGML DTDs (e.g. [the HTML 4.01 script element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)), but not in XML DTDs (hence [the change for XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8)).

Comment: Interesting.  So would this basically mean that I should look for an SGML parser (in PHP) rather than use SimpleXML?  At the end of the da I need to convert the XML into usable objects or arrays.  I'm unfamiliar with SGML.  Thanks!

Comment: Since the document is XML, you should be reporting the bug to the third party providing the data to you, and continuing to fix it up on the fly in the mean time.

Comment: Gotcha.  Looks like I'm going to just hack it until they can fix it then.  Thanks for confirming that!

Comment: Good thread. I keep coming up on it. I am curious if XML DTDs changed in the intervening 4 years or if it might EVER allow one to define "element as CDATA". XML typically stores the payload as the contents of an element, whether that's best practice or not, and in modern programming that payload is likely to contain angle brackets.

Comment: @snakeoil — No.